# alias the product of 2 tables after joining

Tags: mysql, database

okay, so thing is I have 2 different tables and I use an inner join to get the common of the 2 tables. I can alias the new columns after joining just fine but I need to count and show the value of the most common occurrence in the new column. I just couldn't figure a way to do that. However, I find a work around by creating a new table and count the occurrence, give out the value and drop the table. I really want to know what the right way to do this... Here is my code:

```
create table result as 
(
   select department.Dcode as de_code, department.Dname as de_name
   from (department join enroll on department.Dcode = enroll.Dcode)
);

SELECT       result.de_name,
             COUNT(result.de_name) AS occurr
    FROM     result
    GROUP BY result.de_name
    ORDER BY occurr DESC
    LIMIT    1;

drop table result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
SELECT result.de_name, COUNT(result.de_name) AS occurr
FROM
(select department.Dcode as de_code, department.Dname as de_name from department join enroll on department.Dcode = enroll.Dcode) as result
GROUP BY result.de_name
ORDER BY occurr DESC
```

Here `result` is the alias of records returned by the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: much appreciate, now I see where I got wrong before when I tried to alias the newly joined table. I modified the code a little and I got what I wanted, THANK YOU SO MUCH.